# Ruby Excel Sheet Read and generate random number and upload in particular column

Tags: ruby

I have an excel sheet that have these columns:

```
SN Serial CalCode UseBy
```

I have to write a ruby script that will read the excel, generate random 20k records and upload in that excel.

Serial can be of 6 digits i.e. E2QL82

CalCode can be of like i.e. CC3JU-J3GWR

UseBy can be date like 09 Sep 2028

Can someone please help me in generating this.

Answer (score 0):

May be try this program given below

```
# generate 20k random records
(1..20000).each do |i|
  # generate random values
  serial = 'E' + rand(100000..999999).to_s
  cal_code = 'CC' + rand(1000..9999).to_s + '-' + rand(1000..9999).to_s
  use_by = Date.today + rand(365..1095)
end
```

Use the above logic and push the date into using rubyXL gem.